# MVVM repository data layer in swift

Tags: swift, mvvm

What are some techniques and best practices for managing large repositories in MVVM architecture using Swift? How can you ensure that your code remains well-organized, easy to maintain, and easy to debug? Moreover, which frameworks or libraries are suitable for effectively managing extensive datasets, and how do you identify the best approach for your project's unique needs?

**PS: I am using Alamofire for network management.**